# Reverse-ish a string!

Tags: code-golf, string

Your task: write a program/function that when given a string containing only ASCII characters, outputs/returns the string in reverse-ish.

**Example:**

1) Input

```
Hello, World!
```

2) Number unique characters in input. (Input string separated by pipes (`|`) for readability)

```
H|e|l|l|o|,| |W|o|r|l|d|!
1 2 3   4 5 6 7   8   9 10
```

3) For duplicate characters, find the first occurrence of that character and number the duplicate character with the same number as the first.

```
H|e|l|l|o|,| |W|o|r|l|d|!
1 2 3 3 4 5 6 7 4 8 3 9 10
```

4) Reverse the string, but not the numbers.

```
!|d|l|r|o|W| |,|o|l|l|e|H
1 2 3 3 4 5 6 7 4 8 3 9 10
```

5) Delete the characters above repeat numbers. (Deleted characters represented with an asterisk.)

```
!|d|l|*|o|W| |,|*|l|*|e|H
1 2 3 3 4 5 6 7 4 8 3 9 10
```

6) Replace the deleted characters with the character that appears over the first occurrence of the number that the deleted character is over.

```
!|d|l|l|o|W| |,|o|l|l|e|H
1 2 3 3 4 5 6 7 4 8 3 9 10
```

7) Output

```
!dlloW ,olleH
```

**Test cases:**

```
Input -> Output
"Hello, World!" -> "!dlloW ,olleH"
"18464399" -> "99343488"
"Code Golf" -> "floG eloC"
"abcdefgABCDEFG" -> "GFEDCBAgfedcba"
"Mmm, marshmallows" -> "swwllwmhsrwm  mms"
"15147" -> "74751"
```

Comment: For those who can see deleted posts, the sandbox was [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13980/64159).

Comment: Is the string guaranteed to only contain ASCII characters?

Comment: @LeakyNun Yes, I will edit.

Answer (score 21):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 1 byte

```
X
```

**[Verify all the test cases.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=X&input=%22Hello+World%21%22&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22Hello+World%21%22%0A%2218464399%22%0A%22Code+Golf%22%0A%22abcdefgABCDEFG%22%0A%22Mmm%2C+marshmallows%22%0A%2215147%22&debug=0)**

Pyth has wonderful built-ins :-)

---

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io),  <s>8</s>  7 bytes

```
sm@_QxQ
```

**[Verify all the test cases.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=sm%40_QxQ&input=%22Hello+World%21%22&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22Hello+World%21%22%0A%2218464399%22%0A%22Code+Golf%22%0A%22abcdefgABCDEFG%22%0A%22Mmm%2C+marshmallows%22%0A%2215147%22&debug=0)**

#### How it works

This is the more interesting non-built-in approach.

```
sm@_QxQ  - Full program.

 m       - Map over the input.
  @_Q    - Get the index in the reversed input.
     xQ  - Of the first index of each character in the String.
s        - Join the list.
```

Comment: Why does Pyth have this as a built in?  How is it useful other than this question?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah You can read more about this function [here](https://pyth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/spec_seq.html#seq-a-seq-b-seq-c-translate). It is the translate function in Pyth, but if the third argument is missing, the reverse of the second argument is used instead.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>46</s> 41 bytes

<sup>-5 bytes thanks to Artyer</sup>

```python
lambda x:''.join(x[~x.find(n)]for n in x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY8/b4MwFMT3fooXL4DkRqI4BSJRKSEJWTpnoAwmtgOV/yBMBV361Skm2939Tnrvut@hMfptFtnXLKmqGYVp73nbb9Nqfyr/pq1oNfN1UAnTg4ZWwxTMTre6w2B@BheVJbpyKQ2Gm@kl2yAMaMOW4AbYSMmvqMIlChPyTqI0dTRNIxKRJFlBbhiHwkjhiJCmAC5NviJa3xkXj8MxP50vhePF5XzKj4eH4Oxe07X0qRQGRXvbKLocHa3r2XGUclSN7UcFoJR9/rALSexwTOJdiKpq/wJd3@ph3eO9fngYhL/oYDEefsosW3bO/w)

Comment: You can just do `lambda x:''.join(x[~x.find(n)]for n in x)` instead of reversing then indexing

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
iÐ€ịṚ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/z8IRHTWse7u5@uHPW////lQxNDU3MlQA)

Answer (score 5):

### [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 7 bytes

```
q__W%er
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/vzA@Plw1tej/f9/cXB2F3MSi4ozcxJyc/PJiAA)

#### Explanation

```
q   e# Read all input.
__  e# Make two copies.
W%  e# Reverse the third copy.
er  e# Transliterate the input, mapping the input to its own reverse. Due
    e# to the way transliteration works in CJam, if a character in the source
    e# of the mapping is repeated, all but the first occurrence of that
    e# character are ignored.
```

Comment: I wish Jelly's `y` worked like that.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I wish *Alice's* `y` worked like that. :P

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 6 bytes

```
PGt&m)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P8C9RC1X8/9/dY/UnJx8HYXw/KKcFEV1AA)

```
           implicit input
P          flip
 Gt        paste input back to stack and dup
   &m      alternate ismember, returns duplicated indices
     )     apply indices to the reversed char array
           implicit output, print as char
```

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

```
R‡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/6FHDwv//DU0NTcwB)

Explanation:

```
R‡
R  Reverse input
 ‡ Transliterate the input with itself and its reverse (as above) (it only keeps first occurrences)
```

Answer (score 3):

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 17 bytes

```
/?.R?y.@
\i.!yDo/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/1/fXi/IvlLPgSsmU0@x0iVf//9/39xcHYXcxKLijNzEnJz88mIA)

#### Explanation

```
/...@
\.../
```

This is just the usual template for linear code in Ordinal mode. If we unfold this, the actual program simply becomes:

```
i.!?D.?.Ryyo
```

The idea here is similar to that of [my CJam answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/144551/8478). Since Alice has no easy way of indexing into strings with integers, it's easiest to replicate this behaviour with transliteration (`y` in Alice). However, Alice's transliteration semantics are a lot more general than CJam's, which means that Alice doesn't just disregard repeated mappings. For example, if we just wanted to transliterate `Mmm, marshmallows` to its reverse, this would represent the following list of mappings:

```
M -> s
m -> w
m -> o
, -> l
  -> l
m -> a
a -> m
r -> h
s -> s
h -> r
m -> a
a -> m
l ->  
l -> ,
o -> m
w -> m
s -> M
```

Note that we've got, for example, `m -> w`, `m -> o`, `m -> a` and `m -> a`. CJam would just discard all except the first mapping, but Alice would instead cycle through these. So the first `m` would be mapped to `w`, the second to `o`, the fifth again to `w` and so on. In this case that isn't helpful, because in general if we perform `y` on `AAB` (for some strings `A` and `B`) as we did in CJam, we'll always just get `B` in Alice.

So how do we compute a mapping that works for `y` (i.e. how do we discard the repeated mappings manually)? Of course, by using another transliteration. :)

The source of the mapping we want has to be the nub of the input (i.e. the deduplicated input). If we apply the above mapping to the nub, then each character only appears once, so we're only making use of the first of each of the repeated mappings. So by transliterating the nub with the input and its reverse, we're effectively simply discarding the duplicated mappings. We can then use the nub and this new result as a mapping for the original input. I'm sure that made sense to someone...

So the code:

```
i   Read input.                   ["Mmm, marshmallows"]
.!  Store a copy on the tape.
?D  Push the nub of the input.    ["Mmm, marshmallows" "Mm, arshlow"]
.   Duplicate.                    ["Mmm, marshmallows" "Mm, arshlow" "Mm, arshlow"]
?   Retrieve input.               ["Mmm, marshmallows" "Mm, arshlow" "Mm, arshlow" "Mmm, marshmallows"]
.R  Push its reverse.             ["Mmm, marshmallows" "Mm, arshlow" "Mm, arshlow" "Mmm, marshmallows" "swollamhsram ,mmM"]
y   Transliterate.                ["Mmm, marshmallows" "Mm, arshlow" "swllmhsr mm"]]
y   Transliterate.                ["swwllwmhsrwm  mms"]
o   Output.                       []
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript ES6 50 bytes

3 bytes saved thanks to Justin Mariner

```
s=>[...s].map(x=>s.slice(~s.indexOf(x))[0]).join``
```

#### Test it:

```js
f=s=>s.split``.map(x=>s.slice(~s.indexOf(x))[0]).join``

let inp = document.getElementById("inp");
let out = document.getElementById("out");

function change() {
  out.innerText = f(inp.value);
}

change();
```

```html
<input id="inp" type="text" oninput="change()" value="Hello, World!" /><br>
<p id="out"></p>
```

Comment: You can save another 3 bytes by using `s.replace(/./g,...)` instead of `[...s].map(...).join\`\``

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), 7 bytes

```
L@Q_M@s
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=L%40Q_M%40s&input=%22Mmm%2C+marshmallows%22&warnings=0&hex=0)

```
L@      - Get the index of the first index of each character.
  Q     - Push the input to the stack.
   _    - Reverse it.
    M@  - Get the element at (each) position in ^^^ in ^.
      s - Join.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 23 + 1 (`-p`) = 24 bytes

```perl
eval"y/$_/".reverse."/"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z@1LDFHqVJfJV5fSa8otSy1qDhVT0lf6f9/39xcHYXcxKLijNzEnJz88uJ/@QUlmfl5xf91CwA)

*Thanks to @MartinEnder's Alice entry for the transliteration idea*

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>68</s> 65 bytes

```r
function(s)chartr(paste(rev(el(strsplit(s,''))),collapse=''),s,s)
```

[Verify test cases!](https://tio.run/##FYy7jsIwEEV7vsK4YSwNRUSAjQQFb5qttzaOvYk0xtaMAfH1IXT36BxdHqi/seU3RF@61IqZBLWZD@Fxd6VPdxDjOsuFIVspHtg/wRNIYcnUFxCczYwx6BKRzeK3I6KgmEFszvQGB/rqiRKqv8TUTjXq6qde1YumGechtV5dEgWNStuba3343@0Px9P5MtrfGFFFy9JFO1685FtVy6pea4PBDB8)

Ports [Erik's 05AB1E](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/144554/67312) method for 3 bytes less. It wasn't the first, but it was the first one I saw.

### old version:

```r
function(s)paste(rev(s<-el(strsplit(s,'')))[match(s,s)],collapse='')
```

[Verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##FYw7D8IgFEZ3fwWyFBI6NNZXooPW1@LsYBwoD9vkUggXNf76itv5cr6cOELfRhm/zJnUeY18YsmmHO1rUKn3A0MeJCbDonkz3JQGGKaIAfrEUBQF5/zuZFJdXsgfQnkAGdBssxpRhgBfphi9GAAvyM1H0FMqaLWqF/Vsvc7YeG3I2YOlglDZKm3sc7dvDsfTOdurc4I4GbFzMic@@H9V86peUi4sH38) -- prints out the vector with the input as names and the output in quotes below.

A fairly naive implementation, but I don't think this gets shorter in R (and I look forward to being wrong about that). It's essentially an R port of [Rod's python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/144546/67312) but it was developed independently.

Ungolfed explanation:

```r
function(s){
 s <- el(strsplit(s,''))      # string to characters
 r <- rev(s)                  # reverse s
 idx <- match(s,s)            # indices of first matches
 r <- r[idx]                  # do the replacement of duplicates
 paste(r, collapse = "")      # characters to string
}                             # implicit return of last evaluated statement
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 98 bytes

```c
i,n,a[256];char*f(char*c){n=strlen(c);for(i=n;i>0;i--)a[c[i-1]]=c[n-i];for(;i<n;i++)c[i]=a[c[i]];}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZBPT8IwGIfP66eoMyYdbCIKKCkjUVS8ePYwdyjdur2xa5duSAjhs89SvGjEU98/T355@vKo4Lw7B8XlOsvxrGkzCavLco5@zED/HhlQhZ11EKqQJdfjSUp5yUxPEPfwYKdiS8lcER5QoQ2BWFGYX1GIooAlPIFomKYxT1QEqQMozCzR7wd2l8YOSVO671wg3hhWu2zca4Id8gYDXLGPHLdljo86uNIZCGArmSPvSBocW0pKzcm3TBMEFHm24fWWmLA5dC6M1bXcujSxVrwFrZAniDnuTd6ujcKGoj1CoFobCoocCmYKHjrDni0/D2a1lWkF8S@ad@WHztt/ya1EiN@0kdmZ7xz@woZ3o8noZjo9TSy0vf9SS3EaYSue5aK4f1g8Pj0vT3OvVRXaj5imdCfaNP94jYejW7fed18)

Argument must be a modifiable string; string is modified in-place.

Comment: [88 bytes](https://tio.run/##fZBPT8IwGIfP66eoMybdGCIKKCkjUVS8ePYwdyhduzV27dINCSH77LMrXjTiqe@fJ788fekwp7Q7F4rKbcbgom4yKTaXxRL8mAn9e2SEyu2sE5GKSHI9naU45IgWxIQ0OHBtkIhVbDnJFKIBFssrHJCEJsOhSNOYJsq@uOewWCgc0EQMBmncE3aP285FwZ0hlUuFYR0cgDcawZJ8MNgUDB4lYKkzwQXZSAa8I2lgbCkpNUXfAnUQYODZhlZ7ZKK671wYqSq5d2l8q2gjtAIeR@a4N6zZGgUNBi0AQjU2VCjUF8TkNHKGoS0/e7PKyjQc@Rf1u/Ij5@2/MCsRwTdtZHbmO4e/sPHdZDa5mc9PEyttr77Wkp9GyIZmjOf3D6vHp@f1ae61LCP7EVMX7kS7@h@v6Xhy69Zt9wU "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## Java 10, <s>100</s> <s>99</s> 97 bytes

```java
s->{var a=new char[256];int l=s.length,i=l;for(;i>0;a[s[--i]]=s[l+~i]);for(;i<l;s[i]=a[s[i++]]);}
```

Port of [@LeakyNun's C answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/144564/52210). I doubt it can be done shorter without doing something similar in Java.
-1 byte thanks to *@ceilingcat*.

Input as `char[]` (character-array), and modifies this input instead of returning a new one to save bytes.

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##XZExb8IwEIX3/oorUxAkKi3QojRING3pAgtDhyjDkThg6tjINkEIwV9PncRITSVbsu89@Xt33mGBrtgTvkt/yoShUrBAys93AJRrIjNMCCyrK0AhaAqJk2xRRjGorm@qF7PNUho1TWAJHAIolTs9FygBA06OUPsfR@PYNy8CC5THCN/obZ8GzM@EdHw6ffAxUpHr0jgOVMR6Vxp3rfbKfBXROKgMtNeLjXAp/Qa7P6yZwVp6nS836Z2VlpRvTEjsNtE1UdrpfBHGRB@@hWTpfafOf5MGL8Px8GkyaVdDkRKYC5a1y7hOUpJtZm/h@8fnvK0t8rxvQki1zdHQjuofZzQYPnf@jm4vaYGatJqovU0T9TlERWwndvooJZ7MrG@qp0VolFlVdiyRe4lT@@x9dVKa5J44aM9AuWbcqf6n4VinTXYpfwE)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
Ṙ$Ŀ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLhuZgkxL8iLCIiLCJNbW0sIG1hcnNobWFsbG93cyJd)

Answer (score 1):

## [Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda), 27 bytes

```
f x{x|[x[-1-indexOf(_,x)]]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8pPSfz/P02horqiJroiWtdQNzMvJbXCP00jXqdCMza29n9uYmaeQjUXZ5qGkkdqTk6@jkJ4flFOiqKSvpKSJlftfwA)

This takes a list of characters as input and returns a stream of characters.

Using string datatype (40 bytes):

```
f x{x=x/""x|[x[-1-indexOf(_,x)]]|concat}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8pPSfz/P02horrCtkJfSamiJroiWtdQNzMvJbXCP00jXqdCMza2Jjk/LzmxpPZ/bmJmnkI1F2eahpJHak5Ovo5CeH5RToqikiZX7X8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 39 bytes

```arturo
$->s->map s'n->s\[dec-size s index s n]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?IWyhxE)

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 61 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZBda8IwFIbv/RVnxYsE2kKxzg9WQavWi8kuxvBi7CK2ae2WNJLEtUP87S792OYC4cB5n3Py5lUxYeQq9u801rAleQHna0JTSFE1fdYyLzIcVC4nRxQHswpVLqNFpg@O51RuXiS0ekpRjDF2@UeLXwHqeW5WISIzNYW5lOTrtVXf8BReilxDAOcemPNJGGiqdEgUVab7mCuNGgUAWRvKmLBhJyRL7iwbrLvENHZgC8boxsL2L@mN/Xt/MJnU0GQy8Af@eHyrhyKhEAmW1kDKRASUifCWIPvYGM/mi3C5Wkc1Fq1Xy3Axz1KaxHtyy245t80XpTpwYgyVqsZVWTJW8oOSJQfgXP3zN/T8UU2N/NHQs3Aj4F5TUiEBobw4nrQN4qRNxfDg/OWCu7DauCRVJ1YnmLYzuNOOJmDNCqSsftMHZwb9Dnagf/6ZC7o3Lp2LS6@@l971Gw)

```scala
def f(x:String)=x.map(c=>x(x.length-1-x.indexOf(c))).mkString
```